# wp.blocks.blockRegisterType Showing Error in Console - Gutenberg Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am not able to register a gutenberg block for a wordpress site, when I saw console it's showing an error

> 'Uncaught TypeError: wp.blocks.blockRegisterType is not a function at custom-cta-script.js?ver=1:1:11'

can someone help to fix it?

PHP code to enqueue js file:

```
function include_cta_js()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-cta-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'custom-cta-script.js', array(
        'wp-blocks', 'wp-editor'
    ), true, false);
}
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'include_cta_js');
```

JS File:

```
wp.blocks.blockRegisterType('custom-cta-script/custom-block', {
    title: 'CTA',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'text',
    attributes: {
        text: { type: 'string' },
        url: { type: 'string' },
        backgroundColor: { type: 'string' },
        textColor: { type: 'string' }
    },
    edit: function (props) {
        return React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Button Text"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
            type: "text",
            value: "",
            placeholder: "Button Text"
        }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Button URL"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
            type: "text",
            value: "",
            placeholder: "Button URL"
        }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Button Background Color"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
            type: "text",
            value: "",
            placeholder: "Button Background Color"
        }), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("label", null, "Button Text Color"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("input", {
            type: "text",
            value: "",
            placeholder: "Button Text Color"
        }));
    },
    save: function (props) {
        return null;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Gutenberg version 5.8, the function `wp.blocks.registerBlockType()` replaced `wp.blocks.blockRegisterType()` to register a custom block. Therefore, you should replace `wp.blocks.blockRegisterType` with `wp.blocks.registerBlockType` in your JavaScript code.